# Change marker's labelClass on mouseover using jQuery on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I've added the markerwithlabel.js file and can successfully show markers with labels on my google map with this code:

```
markerArray[i] = new MarkerWithLabel({
 position: myLatLng,
 map: map,
 icon: image,
                 labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(25, 30),
                 labelClass: "marker_labels", // the CSS class for the label
                 labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75},
                 labelContent: format_num(property[6]),
 }
);
```

I want to change the class of the label to highlight it when I mouseover another element on the page that corresponds to that marker/label. I've tried with jQuery but just can't get it working:

```
$(".sidelisting").hover(
             function () {
                 $(markerArray[this.id].labelClass).addClass("hovered");
             },
             function () {
                 $(markerArray[this.id].labelClass).removeClass("hovered");
             }
     );
```

The above code doesn't show any javascript errors in the console but nothing happens on mouseover, changing it from `labelClass` to `label` doesn't work either, any ideas?

Comment: The library you're talking about is probably: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.8/docs/reference.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you are using this.id in the hover function. For this to work the elements with class `sidelisting` have to have ids that match the indexes of markerArray.

Secondly:
If `markerArray[this.id].labelClass` isn't undefined, it is probably "marker_labels" and not the DOMNode. This makes `$(markerArray[this.id].labelClass)` create either an empty jquery object or a jquery object that refers to the element with the ID "marker_labels".
You have to call set on the marker to change any property:

```
$(".sidelisting").hover(
         function () {
             markerArray[this.id].set("labelClass", "marker_labels hovered")
         },
         function () {
             markerArray[this.id].set("labelClass", "marker_labels")
         }
 );
```

Comment: yes the `sidelisting`s ids match the indexes of markerArray. I just tried your code now and it works perfectly, thanks very much indeed

Comment: Great answer, was looking on SO for over an hour trying to find this precise answer. Ty